# How to JOIN 4 table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

Currently I have 4 tables. `activity`, `category`, `pic` and `useraccount`.

In this system, there's 2 user: applicant and person-in-charge. applicant will login and request for activity (which will be stored in table activity).

then depend on the category, person-in-charge will be assigned(will be stored in table pic with their name and `activityID`)

```
activity: `activityID`(PK), `username`, `categoryID`
category: `categoryID`(PK), `categoryName`
pic: `activityID`, `personincharge` (name of the pic)  
useraccount: `name`, `username`
```

note: `personincharge` in table pic and `name` in table useraccount has the same value.

note 2: I will join table category and activity using `categoryID` to display the `categoryname`.

My system is going to have user log in by using `username`. I want to display table of activity record of the person in charge, which means it will only shows activity that the user(the one who logged in) is in charge of.

Currently I am only able to join table category and activity and display it. Here's what I have:

```
$sql = "
SELECT * 
  FROM activity a
  JOIN category c 
    ON a.categoryID = c.categoryID
 WHERE a.username= '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Gone through so many trial and error but still cant find the answer. Thanks for the help in advance.

**the flow of my system:**
situation 1:
user login -> user request activity -> admin will pick the person in charge of the activity (the name of the pic will be insert into pic table along with the activityID)

situation 2:
pic login -> pic see the list of activity that he/she has been assigned to be in charge of and take action on the request.

**the situation 2 is what i'm currently stuck on. to display only activity he/she is assigned to.

Comment: THERE IS SQL INJECTION SECURITY RISK HERE

Comment: This isn't a 'prepared statement' !?!

Comment: @philipxy i've already mention the place where i'm stuck at. i want to display the list of activity that the person-in-charge was assigned to after the pic logged in. the problem is at the query, joining table.

Comment: That is not what your post says, it is not clear. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing inner joins, then you can also join using the where clause, like so:

`SELECT * 
FROM activity as a, 
category as c, 
pic as p, 
useraccount as u
WHERE a.categoryID = c.categoryID, 
a.activityID = p.activityID, 
p.personincharge = u.name`

Comment: This is not a good way to do joins. This syntax is from the 90s and is not good practice. If you are using this you should stop.

Comment: You need joins only for special cases of outer joins. When you want rows matching all the joins, but no partiall joins. That's when JOIN was introduced to the standard. There is no other difference.

Answer (score 0):

One:
Do not name your tables after smart shortcuts. Think what you are optimizing, and what you are loosing! Use "table AS t" shortcuts in actual queries.

Two:
Your table personsincharge contain the people responsible. Do a join with it. accountname is **requester** account. Once you join presonsincharge you have access to **handlers**

Three:
**DO NOT USE POST VALUES TO CONCATENATE SQL STRINGS**

Comment: 1. after changing what you told. nothing much happen. still the same error. still cant display what i want.
2. that's what i've been doing and the answers here too, joining with the table personincharge. in your case, who is the handlers?  
3. i didnt use post values.

Answer (score -1):

You could have multiple joins in the same query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM activity a 

INNER JOIN category c ON a.categoryID=c.categoryID
INNER JOIN table_name as table_alias ON table_alias.ID = another_alias.ID
INNER JOIN ...
INNER JOIN ........
INNER JOIN ......

WHERE a.username= '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Comment: THERE IS SQL INJECTION SECURITY RISK HERE

Comment: Yes, he wants to understand, he does not want to put security ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select a.activityID, b.categoryName, c.personincharge, d.name
FROM activity a 
LEFT JOIN category b ON b.categoryID = a.categoryID 
LEFT JOIN pic c ON c.activityID = a.activityID 
LEFT JOIN useraccount d ON d.username = a.username
WHERE d.username= '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
```

Comment: Your final join renders as an inner join. Was that your intention?

Comment: @Strawberry yes

Comment: In that case, it seems sensible to write it as an [INNER] JOIN